# Is it possible to mature shop-bought hard cheese?

Tags: flavor, cheese

Is there a way in which I can continue the maturation process for blocks of shop-bought cheddar (or other hard) cheese of around 190g "packed in a protective atmosphere". The cheese is too bland for my taste.

Comment: You can dry it out some cheeses, which will intensify the flavor a bit, but it's not really maturing.

Comment: Or soak it in port?

Comment: Which hard cheese are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can mature cheeses, most hard cheeses can be matured either in the refridgerator or elsewhere.  Remove from the plastic packaging, the cheese will need to breathe, but not dry out - a cardboard box, paper towels, parchment paper would work.  Just be careful on the amount of moisture & bacteria/mold growth.

You'll find a lot more helpful information if you search on "maturing cheeses" or "maturing cheeses at home".

Comment: I don't know if wax sealing would be appropriate for this, but that's a standard protective layer when making cheese.